# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list [Using a Dictionary]

Tags: python, dictionary

Essentially, I am creating a count by using a dictionary and everytime it sees a "1" in the text file, it adds one to the array.However, I keep getting an error

```
Letters = ["A","B,"C","D","E","F"]
d= {}
d["A"] = [0]
d["B"] = [0]
d["C"] = [0]
d["D"] = [0]
d["E"] = [0]
file = open('test1.txt','r')
for line in file:
    line_array = line.strip("\n").split(",")
    for x in range(5):
        if line_array[x] == "1":
            for y in Letters:
                d[y][0] = d[y][0] + 1
```

BTW, the text file is formatted like this;

```
1,0,3,0,2
0,2,1,0,3
ETC
```

EDIT sorry, misworded

Comment: I do not really see why you actually use lists over simple integers.

Comment: (scratching the head), how are you even able to access list indices with string ?

Comment: `Letters` is a `list` not a `dict` in your code (see first line). `d` is a dictionary, but you're not using it.

Comment: Be specific about the error. The first issue I see is that `Letters` is a list, so `Letters["A"]` should give you a `TypeError` because lists expect integer indexes.

Comment: Your posted code fails at the second line.  You're trying to use a list as if it were already a dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually use your dictionary.

```
Letters= ["A","B","C","D","E"]
d= {key: 0 for key in Letters}
print(Letters)
file = open('test1.txt','r')
for line in file:
    line_array = line.strip("\n").split(",")
    for x in range(5):
        if line_array[x] == "1":
            for i, value in enumerate(Letters):
                if i == x:
                    d[value] = d[value] + 1
#print(candidatescores) # No idea where this comes from
```

Comment: This then leads to ALL the lines in the text file adding up and the value for each key is the same

Comment: Fixed. Note that this is based on you wanting a dictionary, but the problem on its own would be much more trivial using normal lists/tuples.

Comment: why not use csv to read the csv file? Also, ```if i = x``` is missing an equals sign. ```line.rstrip()``` will remove the newline. Finally, ```file``` is a reserved word in Python :)